# Kotlin multiple constructor error: declaration have same java signature

Tags: android, kotlin, higher-order-functions, constructor-overloading, multiple-constructors

I have two constructors in `FirebaseUserAuth` class and it is giving an Error: declaration have same java signature. The parameter of constructors are different. Why is it giving same signature error?
how to fix it?.

```
class FirebaseUserAuth(private val auth: FirebaseAuth,
                       private val loginCallBack: ((LoginAuthData) -> Unit)?,
                       private val registerVM_CallBack: ((RegisterAuthData) -> Unit)?)
{

  constructor(auth: FirebaseAuth, loginCallBack: (LoginAuthData) -> Unit): this(auth, loginCallBack, null)
  constructor(auth: FirebaseAuth, registerCallBack: (RegisterAuthData) -> Unit): this(auth, null, registerCallBack)
}
```

Error

```
> Platform declaration clash:The following declarations have the same JVM
> signature (Lcom/google/fireBase/auth/FirebaseAuth;Lkotlin/jvm/
> functions/Function1;)V):
> 
>  • public constructor FirebaseUserAuth(auth: FirebaseAuth,
> loginCallBack: (LoginAuthData) -> Unit) defined.
> com.examgle.data.FirebaseUserAuth 
> 
>  • public constructor FirebaseUserAuth(auth: FirebaseAuth,
> registerCallBack: (RegisterAuthData) -> Unit) defined.
> com.examgle.data.FirebaseUserAuth
```

Comment: Use a Single constructor with Generic Type of function parameter ..

Comment: @ADM Thank you!!! i used Generic Type and its working

Answer (score 2):

```
constructor(auth: FirebaseAuth, loginCallBack: (LoginAuthData) -> Unit)
constructor(auth: FirebaseAuth, registerCallBack: (RegisterAuthData) -> Unit)
```

Both constructor are same as the type of the function parameter in `JAVA` is `Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1`.

**Check this through:**

1. `Menu > Tools > Kotlin > Show Kotlin Bytecode`
2. Click on the `Decompile` button
3. Check the java code

My suggestion is to use **default** parameter rather than secondary constructor if possible:

```
class FirebaseUserAuth(private val auth: FirebaseAuth,
                       private val loginCallBack: ((LoginAuthData) -> Unit)? = null,
                       private val registerVM_CallBack: ((RegisterAuthData) -> Unit)? = null)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: but different data type `loginCallBack: (LoginAuthData) -> Unit)` , `registerCallBack: (RegisterAuthData) -> Unit)` in function parameter

Comment: Both are function in java despite of data type

Comment: Is there any way to tell the compiler to differentiate it